# how to overload accessor and mutator operator[] in c++

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I want to write a **String** class. And want to use subscript to access element in my **String**. So, I write two member function, one to get the element in the **String**, and another to set the element in the **String**. Please look at following code;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class String {
public:
    String();

    String(const char *s);

    char &operator[] (int index);
    char operator[] (int index) const;

private:
    char *arr;
    int len;
};

String::String() {
    arr = new char[1];
    arr[0] = '\0';
    len = 0;
}

String::String(const char *s) {
    len = strlen(s);
    arr = new char[len + 1];
    std::copy(s, s + len + 1, arr);
}

//mutator operator[] ---> used to change data members;
char& String::operator[](int index)
{
    cout << "mutator []" << endl;
    if (index > len || index < 0)
        throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
    return arr[index];
}
//Accessor operator[]---> used to read data members
char String::operator[](int index) const
{
    cout << "accessor []" << endl;
    if (index > len || index < 0)
        throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
    return arr[index];
}

int main()
{
    String s1 = "abc";

    s1[1] = 'b';  //---> should use mutator operator
    String s2 = "efg";
    s2[1] = s1[2]; //---> should use both accessor and mutator operator
    char a = s1[2]; //---> should use accessor operator
    cout << s2[1] << endl; //---> should use accessor operator
}
```

when I run this code. It's outputs are all `mutator`; It confuses me a lot;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's see this case with the point of view of the compiler. I present you this code:

```
String s2;

/* things */ s1[2] /* things */
```

What function do you choose? The accessor or the mutator? Since `s2` is not a const object, let's take the non-const version!

That's why your code is always printing `mutator`, the compiler will not choose which function to call depending of what you do with the result. Whether you call the `char`'s assignment operator or not.

And your const version should not return a copy, but a const reference:

```
char& operator[](size_t index);
const char& operator[](size_t index) const;
```

You will get a compilation error instead of a value not assigned if you try to write into a const string.

Answer (score 7):

`char operator[] (int index) const;` will only be called when you have a `const String`.  If we change your `main()` to:

```
int main()
{
    const String s1 = "abc";
    char a = s1[2]; //---> should use accessor operator
}
```

It will ouptut:

```
accessor []
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04fbd66e7fc28eee)</kbd>